# See definition of a word inside a hyperlink in Safari?

Tags: safari, trackpad, dictionary, look-up

For normal text, three-finger tap on a word is Safari works as "Look Up". From a recent version of Safari, the same three-finger tap on a hyperlink works as "Quick Look".

Then, is there any way to view definition of a word that happened to be inside a hyperlink? I have tried tapping with modifiers such as Shift, Control,or Option, but they did not have any special effect.

Personally, I think "Look Up" is more useful than "Quick Look", so I would not mind disabling Quick Look entirely, if I have to.